# How do I show the pairs that must belong to an equivalence relation, $C$, on the real line that contains the set $S$?

Tags: analysis

Let $S\def\and{\text{ and }}$ be the subset of $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$:  $S = \{(x,y) \mid y = x + 1 \and 0 < x < 2\}$.  For example, by reflexivity, $\{(x,y) \mid y = x \and 0 < x < 2\}$ , $(x,y)$ belongs to $C$;  by symmetry,
$\{(x,y) \mid y = x - 1 \and 1 < x < 3\}$ belongs to $C$.

By transitivity and symmetry, I have read on a dbfin solutions' website that $\{(x,y) \mid y + 2 (0 < x < 1)\}$ and
$\{(x,y) \mid (y - 2) (2 < x < 3)\}$ belong to $C$.  But I have not been able to show this to my satisfaction.

I need a hint or two to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply transitivity:

Let's write $a\sim b$ for $(a,b)\in C$.
Assume $0<x<1$, then in particular $x<2$, so $x\sim (x+1)$, but $x+1$ is still between $0$ and $2$, thus $(x+1)\sim(x+2)$, and transitivity yields $x\sim(x+2)$.
Apply $(a,b)\in C\land (b,c)\in C\implies (a,c)\in C$ to $a=x,\ b=x+1\, c=x+2$.

The other statement is similar, indeed symmetry is also involved there.

Comment: C is an eqv relation on R and a subset of RxR; given.   C contains the subset S; given.   All elements of S are (x,y)s where y = x + 1, provided that (0 < x < 2); given.  The elements of the equivalent relation C are points (x,y) according to my understanding.  These points are all equivalent.   If (x,y) in S, then (x,x) is in C, by reflexivity.   If (x,y) is in S, then (y,x) is in C, by symmetry.  Thus, some (x,y) have y=x+1, and some (x,y) have y=x-1.   We now have 3 varieties of (x,y):  (x,x); and (x,y) in S: and (x,y) in the refection of S in the line y=x, by symmetry.   How transivity?

Comment: For example, we have $(0.2,\,1.2)\in C$ and $(1.2,\, 2.2)\in C$. Transitivity yields $(0.2,\,2.2)$.